# How do you re-log errors to another Cloudwatch Stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am monitoring our Serverless AWS Lambda application using Cloudwatch and Cloudwatch insights. In order to cut down cost on displaying errors and error graphs, I want to re-log our errors to an additional stream that is separate from all our normal interactions with our users.

I know you can add Cloudwatch subscriptions with filters, but when I try to use Kenesis Firehose, it only has those streaming to external log providers. What is the correct or best way to re-log these to another Cloudwatch stream if they meet a filter constraint?

Comment: Why do you need another stream? Usually the use case is export to s3, or external log monitoring system as you said, then you can do whatever you want (analytics, etc.).

Comment: @RegisterSole Because most of our logs are normal non-error sessions. It gets costly looking back at error graphs if I have to parse 100's of GB of logs to see the errors. If I can re-log only errors to a new stream, the data is very small and I could graph back months at at almost no cost on our dashboards if I wanted to.

Comment: Ok then why not relog to s3? Then use Athena for example. As s3 is more versatile than CloudWatch, and as AWS doesn't allow CloudWatch as Firehose destination, I think that's what AWS intended for your use case.